# How to save a packed image from a script

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to save a packed image (generated via texture painting). To do this, I call `unpack()`, which should save the image, but I can't find it on my hard drive (Linux, blender 2.73). Does there exist a way for further customization (such as setting the image file format, file name, directory to save into, ..)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs reference [*unpack*](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.ops.image.html?highlight=unpack#bpy.ops.image.unpack)

Given an image with the super descriptive name 'Untitled':

[image]

```
>>> bpy.ops.image.unpack(id='Untitled')
Warning: AutoPack is enabled, so image will be packed again on file save
Info: Saved packed file to: /home/zeffii/Downloads/textures/dances_packed.png

{'FINISHED'}
```

If you look in console you'll see where it saved to.

But it is possible for certain to use plain old `.save()` too. Opening a .blend where the image is packed I did

```
bpy.data.images['Untitled'].filepath = '/home/zeffii/Desktop/some_name.png'
bpy.data.images['Untitled'].save()
```

And it stored straight to desktop

**Things I don't know**

How to save as a different file type, and how to force a different save directory for the unpack command.

Comment: Worth noting that you can call unpack without resorting to `bpy.ops` - `bpy.data.images["Untitled"].unpack()`  - See: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=unpack#bpy.types.Image.unpack  You can set the filepath, then call `unpack`

Comment: cool. will work that into the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @ideasman42 why might I get the error `RuntimeError: Error: Image not packed` when running image.unpack() , the image is listed in datablock outliner in packed_files..

Comment: I called unpack directly on an Image [instance](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Image.html), didn't use ops. There was no Info issued. Where's the catch?

Comment: @zeffii, not sure, maybe this should be a bug report.